# iOS React Native - The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

Since yesterday I cannot test my React-Native Apps anymore (not on simulator nor on device). I did uninstall Xcode and re-install. I am testing now with a `init AwesomeProject` file. Xcode reports "Build Successful" and starts displaying the Launch Screen but then I receive the following message

> "[error][tid:main] The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory"

and the Simulator includes message

> "RCTFatal" and "RCTBatchedBridge stopLoadingWithError"

etc
and looks like this:
[Screenshot of ErrorMessage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H335g.png)

**Important**: I was able to build a clean iOS only Test App whose Build did run successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your AppDelegate.m file, check the following line

```
jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true"];
```

If the path is not set to **localhost**, the emulator won't work. If you want to run the app in your phone, have your IP address instead of localhost.

Answer (score 1):

I also experienced this issue and I think it is the same as is discussed on https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3174, where the problem concerns IPv4/IPv6.

What worked for me: I put an IPv6 address in `AppDelegate.m`. This worked for the simulator (iOS 8.4/9.0/9.1) *and* device (iPhone, iOS 9.1):

- you get your IPv6 address with: `ifconfig | grep inet6 | grep -v fe80::`
- in `AppDelegate.m` surround it with brackets, so that:

```m
jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://[abab:1234:1234:abab:aaaa:bbbb:1111:2222]:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true"];
```

---

A more detailed story, concerning IPv4/6 addresses in `AppDelegate.m`:

- in simulator:

  - iOS 9.0 and 9.1:

    - IPv4 doesn't work, however a hostname such as `localhost` does
    - IPv6 works
  - iOS 8.4:

    - IPv4 and IPv6 work
- on device, iPhone with iOS 9.1:

  - IPv4 actually does work for me
  - IPv6 also works